# The road in the graph

Tags: list-manipulation, graphs-and-networks

Consider the graph:

```
kk={4612<->4613,4613<->4614,4642<->4612,4614<->4522,4798<->4642,4522<->4376,4536<->4798,4798<->4996,4376<->4201,4338<->4536,4813<->4996,4201<->4043,4074<->4338,4813<->4735,4043<->3813,3796<->4074,4646<->4735,3711<->3813,3665<->3796,4646<->4585,3711<->3450,3509<->3665,4584<->4585,3119<->3450,3177<->3509,4662<->4584,3119<->2911,2890<->3177,4729<->4662,2911<->2714,2642<->2890,4729<->4753,2551<->2714,2641<->2642,4875<->4753,2518<->2551,4972<->4875,2481<->2518,5081<->4972,2365<->2481,4967<->5081,2320<->2365,4938<->4967,2310<->2320,4937<->4938,2215<->2310,2310<->2317,4942<->4937,2053<->2215,2315<->2317,4923<->4942,1943<->2053,2315<->2316,4922<->4923,1942<->1943,2329<->2316,4880<->4922,2329<->2248,4721<->4880,2248<->2249,4673<->4721,4683<->4721,2249<->2246,4672<->4673,4508<->4683,2246<->2191,4831<->4672,4507<->4508,2191<->2093,4779<->4831,2093<->2052,4551<->4779,4717<->4779,2052<->2000,4551<->4409,4489<->4717,2000<->1961,4274<->4409,4323<->4489,1961<->1950,4224<->4274,4084<->4323,1950<->1951,4223<->4224,3876<->4084,1951<->1957,4336<->4223,3769<->3876,1957<->1948,4336<->4069,4232<->4336,3704<->3769,1948<->1949,3767<->4069,4103<->4232,3545<->3704,2054<->1949,3561<->3767,4055<->4103,3409<->3545,2054<->1996,3415<->3561,3899<->4055,3408<->3409,1996<->1997,3415<->3377,3898<->3899,3425<->3408,2043<->1997,3345<->3377,3905<->3898,3461<->3425,2043<->2128,3277<->3345,3689<->3905,3410<->3461,2091<->2128,3277<->3105,3459<->3689,3360<->3410,2091<->1946,2923<->3105,3458<->3459,3254<->3360,1946<->1838,2822<->2923,2923<->2894,3458<->3460,3239<->3254,1725<->1838,2772<->2822,2894<->2788,3407<->3460,3238<->3239,1725<->1531,2771<->2772,2788<->2598,3406<->3407,1531<->1342,2480<->2598,3514<->3406,1342<->1276,2480<->2402,3321<->3514,3514<->3504,1219<->1276,2402<->2400,3153<->3321,3504<->3272,1219<->1090,2400<->2401,3042<->3153,3023<->3272,1090<->1035,2793<->3042,3084<->3042,2850<->3023,997<->1035,2424<->2793,3008<->3084,2739<->2850,997<->960,2134<->2424,3007<->3008,2578<->2739,2739<->2645,960<->961,1914<->2134,2488<->2578,2645<->2356,1656<->1914,2278<->2488,2195<->2356,1655<->1656,2277<->2278,2195<->2023,1896<->2023,1895<->1896,2772<->1,1<->2,2<->3,2<->4,3277<->100,4<->5,5<->6,5<->7,5<->8,5<->9};

g1=Graph[kk]; 

gl1 = VertexList[g1]; 

gl2 = Table[VertexDegree[g1, gl1[[i]]], {i, 1, Length[gl1]}]; 

gl3 = Flatten[Position[gl2, _?(# != 2 &)]]; gl4 = Table[gl1[[gl3[[i]]]], {i, 1, Length[gl3]}]; 

g2=HighlightGraph[g1, Flatten[gl4], VertexSize -> 2, ImageSize -> 1200]
```

The graph g2 is a graph g1 with the designation of nodes with degree !=2.
How to reduce the graph g2 to the weighted graph i.e. without nodes degree 2 where the weights are the number of removed nodes of degree 2. It looks like this:
[image]

I started like that:

```
gp = GraphPeriphery[g1, Method -> "PseudoDiameter"];

pu1 = Select[Subsets[gp, 2], Length[#] >= 2 &];

pu2 = Sort[Table[{Length[FindShortestPath[g1, pu1[[i, 1]], pu1[[i, 2]]]], pu1[[i]]}, {i, 1, Length[pu1]}], #1[[1]] > #2[[1]] &];

pu3 = pu2[[1, 2]];

gl1 = FindShortestPath[g1, pu3[[1]], pu3[[2]]];

gl2 = Table[VertexDegree[g1, gl1[[i]]], {i, 1, Length[gl1]}];

gl3 = Flatten[Position[gl2, _?(# != 2 &)]];

gl4 = Table[gl1[[gl3[[i]]]], {i, 1, Length[gl3]}];

gl5 = Partition[gl4, 2, 1];

gl6 = Flatten[Table[{Length[FindShortestPath[g1, gl5[[i, 1]], gl5[[i, 2]]]] - 1}, {i, 1, Length[gl5]}]];

gl7 = Table[{gl5[[i, 1]] <-> gl5[[i, 2]], gl6[[i]]}, {i, 1,Length[gl5]}]
```

I will make calculations for large graphs, e.g. as here:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1EUaH6x8mZ-QYq3PKQNNzKdLN_7eQ-Sa2?usp=sharing

Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`IGSmoothen` from [IGraph/M](https://github.com/szhorvat/IGraphM) does basically this: it [smoothens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeomorphism_(graph_theory)#Subdivision_and_smoothing) degree-2 vertices.

It removes degree-2 vertices, i.e. in `1 - 2 - 3` it merges the edges `1 - 2` and `2 - 3` into a single edge `1 - 3`. The weights of the original edges are added up.  `IGSmoothen` considers all edges in an unweighted graph to have weight 1, thus it will effectively count how many edges were merged.

Demo on your graph:

```
IGSmoothen[g1, EdgeLabels -> "EdgeWeight", 
 VertexShapeFunction -> "Name", PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"]
```

[image]

`IGSmoothen` is partially implemented in C++ and will be much faster than any alternative written in pure WL.

Should you want to round edge weights to integers (`IGSmoothen` creates reals by default), just apply the function `IGEdgeMap[Round, EdgeWeight]` to the resulting graph.  It is an operator that applies `Round` to every value of the `EdgeWeight` edge property.

Comment: Thank you a lot!